# ManicTime alternative for Mac

Tags: osx, time-management

Im looking for an app like [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) to use standalone on a Mac. Basically I want to track active windows, websites, and open documents and display in in a timeline like:

[image]

So basically I want a time series graph that has the application and document/page open plotted over a day. I want to be able to go back in time to see what I did that day (up to 1 month). Prefer it to be free, or < $10-$20.

Comment: Please describe your needs exactly, the picture is not clear and you might focus on things that you don't care about. If you don't detail your needs, we can't help you.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul added a little more detail, let me know if you think I am missing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my app [Timing](https://timingapp.com). It tracks which applications you used and which documents you had open, but does not yet (?) display a time series graph. You can see where your time went on any given day however. And at $24.99, it is almost in your desired price range.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

while not an ideal replacement, [rescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com) is a cross-platform program you might want to look into. it sits quietly in the tray collecting your data which you can later see in your online dashboard. its main focus is increasing productivity so in the main view you can see just a breakdown of how productive your activities were on a given date, but you can also see a breakdown of all different applications, websites etc.

[image: main page]

Comment: I currently use this, but it is far from perfect. It doesn't track open documents/pages etc. It doesn't give me an exact breakdown by hour. It even only shows like the top 10 apps.